# T SQL check null syntax confusion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I keep on writing the select statement where value is null in SQL server as

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE VALUE = NULL
```

which is incorrect

Rather than

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE VALUE IS NULL
```

What is the reason why `IS` used to check the value when it is null but `=` is used when the value is an integer or string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that `NULL` is not a value, but a lack of value. The ANSI standard states that the check `NULL = NULL` and `NULL <> NULL` both does not return true, but NULL. Think of NULL as "unknown value". If you compare `3=3`, it will return true, but if you compare `is some number, that I do not know, equal to some other number, which I do not know either`, the the obvious result is `I do not know are they equal`.

You may want to take a look at [ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) option too.

Comment: You don't want to mess around with `set ansi nulls` - it's deprecated and will always be on in next versions of SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 1):

Because `VALUE=NULL` gives a result of `NULL`, and if you use it in a `WHERE` statement it will be *treated* as `false`, just like if you used `NOT VALUE=NULL` which also evaluates to `NULL`. 
Let me explain the above, just to clarify when I say **treated as false**. 
If you use in your statement:

```
WHERE value = NULL
```

or

```
WHERE NOT (value = NULL)
```

you will not get any rows. 
If you use:

```
WHERE value = NULL AND id = 1
```

again you will not get any rows.
**But** if you use:

```
WHERE value = NULL OR id = 1
```

you will get 1 row, the one with `id = 1`.
`NULL` is an alias of *missing* or *unknown* and cannot be used in a place where a valid value like `1` or `'something'` can be used.

Comment: `VALUE=NULL` evaluates to `UNKNOWN` - not `FALSE`. If it was `false` then negating it would yield `true`

Comment: @MartinSmith *If it was false then negating it would yield true* No it would not. Negating wil result in `NOT NULL` which is also `NULL`.

Comment: Negating it will result in `NOT UNKNOWN` which results in `UNKNOWN`. SQL uses three valued logic `false`, `true` and `unknown`. unknown is not the same as false. The reference to false in your answer is false.

Comment: @MartinSmith When I say *finally false* I mean when you use it in a WHERE clause it is finally treated as `false`.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you mention 3VL and explain that the `WHERE` clause only brings back rows where the predicate evaluates to `true`. The reference to `false` is misleading.

Comment: @MartinSmith So if I use `WHERE VALUE = NULL` should I expect any rows?

Comment: No, because that predicate evaluates to `unknown` - and the `where` clause filters out all rows except those for which the predicate evaluates to `true`. rows where the predicate evaluates to either `false` or `unknown` are not returned.

Comment: @MartinSmith exactly. It is *treated* as `false`

Comment: I've given you a suggestion as to how you improve your answer. Take it or leave it. I'm done here

Comment: @MartinSmith you should be.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of SQL Server, `NULL = NULL` is true only in the following two cases:

- when set operators are used (EXECEPT, INTERSECT, UNION, UNION ALL)
- when values in unique constraints are checked

In all other cases, `NULL = NULL` is false.

That's the reason, it is safe to work with the `SET` operators when two result sets are manipulated and why we are allowed to have only one `NULL` value in an unique constraint.